# Laravel token mismatch error after cache clear

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I am using Laravel 5.4 version

What i eana ask when i am clear the browser cache and try to login this time it returning me the error like

```php
TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 68:
```

but when i refresh it again and login it logged in successfully but whenever i clear the browser cache and try to login all the time it returning me the error. can any one please help me related this?

code i have in my `v\VerifyCsrfToken.php` is:

```php
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (
        $this->isReading($request) ||
        $this->runningUnitTests() ||
        $this->shouldPassThrough($request) ||
        $this->tokensMatch($request)
    ) {
        return $this->addCookieToResponse($request, $next($request));
    }

    throw new TokenMismatchException;
}
```

but when i am using this code instead of laravel default :

```php
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $response = $next($request);

    if (last(explode('\\',get_class($response))) != 'RedirectResponse') {
        $response->header('P3P', 'CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"');
    }

    return $response; 
}
```

It's working fine it means after cache clear it allow me to login without giving the token mismatch error.

My question is i dont want to change the default code of laravel so is there any other way to solve this?

Comment: Anyone have any idea ???

Comment: When you are clearing the browser cache the cookie generated for csrf token is also destroyed, that's why it is showing error. In that case you have to refresh the page so that the csrf token is generated again.

Comment: Yes you are getting my point exactly but is there any other option without refreshing can we solve this ??? as i said earlier above code is working fine but i  dont want any changes in default laravel structure ..

Comment: First of all let me know the exact requirement ?

Comment: @Mayank Pandeyz after browser cahe clear i am not able to login directly it showing me the tokenmismatch error but after refresh the page everything is working fine

Comment: My point is, how many users will try this with your live application?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172949/discussion-between-mayank-pandeyz-and-shruti).

Comment: It's unlikely end users are going to clear their browser Cache before submitting a form. If you really need to handle this use case, you could catch the `TokenMismatchException` and either bypass it or return a redirect back to the form and make them submit it again. Try to balance complexity vs value of solution; this is going to be heavily weighted toward complexity without much value if you find a solution...

Answer (score 0):

In app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php,

```
class VerifyCsrfToken extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        //
    ];
}
```

add logout into this array:

```
    protected $except = [
    '/logout'
];
```

Hope this resolves the token mismatch exception. Thanks.

Comment: Please check in incognito mode of the browser.

Comment: @ Saibal Roy  i was not asking for that kind of solution i need a solution for all the browser so please help me .. that was not a solution